# Adding a CSS class to fields in django.contrib.auth.views.login

Tags: css, django, django-forms, django-templates

I'm still fairly new to django, and have come across Django forms for the first time through my use of the `django.contrib.auth.views.login` view, used when Django needs a user to authenticate.

I cannot however figure out how to add a CSS class to the username and password fields and the documentation doesn't specify how I can achieve it.  Ideally I'd like to simply add the additional info to the template tag, such as `{{ form.username | class="usernameclass" }}` or whatever, or even write the field out manually, such as `<input type="{{ form.password.type }}" name="{{ form.password.name }}" class="form-field-password"/>`, but if I need to add a custom view to achieve this I can try that way.

The files related to this are below:

*templates/login.html:*

```
{% load url from future %}

...

<form method="post" action="{% url 'django.contrib.auth.views.login' %}">
{% csrf_token %}
<span class="heading">{{ form.username.label_tag }}</span><br/>
{{ form.username }}<br/>
<span class="heading">{{ form.password.label_tag }}</span><br/>
{{ form.password }}<br/>
<div id="login-button">
<input type="submit" value="Log In" />
<input type="hidden" name="next" value="{{ next }}" />
</div>          
</form>

...
```

*settings.py:*

```
...

LOGIN_URL = '/login/'

...
```

*urls.py*

```
...

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', 'portal.views.home', name='home'),
    url(r'^login/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.login', {'template_name': 'login.html'}),
    url(r'^logout/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.logout'),

    ...

)
```

Any advice is much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This app](https://bitbucket.org/kmike/django-widget-tweaks/overview) will do exactly what you need.